# Calculating interest rate Newton's method in R

Tags: r

We have to compute the following and I am totally clueless.

A consumer asks for a credit of 200000 euro to buy a new house. The bank suggests the following repayment scheme: monthly payments (starting a month after the loan is made) of 2000 euro for 30 years. Use newton root to determine the monthly interest rate that the consumer is exposed to. Set the tolerance level to ε = 0.000001.

This is my algorithm which basically works but I have problems to implement it.

```
  x0 <- 0
  n <- 0
while (n <= n_max) {
  n <- n + 1
  y0 <- f(x0)
  y1 <- f_prime(x0)
  if (y1 < eps) {
    break(0)
  }
  x1 <- x0 - (y0/y1)
  if (abs((x0 - x1) / x1) < eps) {
    print('convergent')
    break(0)
  }
  x0 <- x1
  print(paste(label = 'iterations', n, label = 'approximate root', x0))
  }
}
newton_root()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is right, the code is not. Here it is, corrected.
At the end there is a `uniroot` solution, verifying the code's solution.

```
newton_root <- function(f, f_prime, x_initial = 0, n_max = 50, eps, params){ 
  x0 <- x_initial
  n <- 0
  while (n <= n_max) {
    n <- n + 1
    y0 <- f(x0, params)
    y1 <- f_prime(x0, params)
    if (y1 < eps) {
      break
    }
    x1 <- x0 - (y0/y1)
    if (abs((x0 - x1) / x1) < eps) {
      message('convergent')
      break
    }
    x0 <- x1
    msg <- sprintf("iterations: %d, approximate root: %f", n, x0)
    message(msg)
  }
  x0
}
f <- function(r, params){
  K <- params[1]
  m <- params[2]
  Tot <- params[3]
  K*(1 + r)^m - Tot
}
f_prime <- function(r, params){
  K <- params[1]
  m <- params[2]
  K*m*(1 + r)^(m - 1)
}

pars <- c(200000, 30, 2000*12*30)
tol <- 1e-6
newton_root(f, f_prime, eps = tol, params = pars)
#iterations: 1, approximate root: 0.086667
#iterations: 2, approximate root: 0.061219
#iterations: 3, approximate root: 0.047266
#iterations: 4, approximate root: 0.043800
#iterations: 5, approximate root: 0.043623
#iterations: 6, approximate root: 0.043622
#convergent
#[1] 0.04362246

uniroot(f, c(0, 1), pars, tol = tol)$root
#[1] 0.04362262
```

Comment: Explaining the code presented, and how it corrects problems in the original, will make this answer far more useful.